# How to show C++ style include syntax in doxygen

Tags: c++, doxygen

I am putting doxygen comment in my file. When I generat HTML files (using doxygen application) I can see

**MyClass Class Reference**

```
#include <myclass.hpp>
```

Which I want to display like

**MyClass Class Reference**

```
#include <MyClass>
```

I tried various option but no luck. I tried \file MyClass, but still showing same (above mentioned) line.

Here is doxygen comment

```
/**
 * \class MyClass
 *
 * \ingroup demo
 *
 * \brief Provide an example
 *
 * This class is meant as an example.  It is not useful by itself
 * rather its usefulness is only a function of how much it helps
 * the reader.  It is in a sense defined by the person who reads it
 * and otherwise does not exist in any real form. 
 *
 * \file MyClass
 *
 * Contact: abc@abc.com
 *
 * Created on: Wed Apr 13 18:39:37 2005
 *
 */
```

Comment: what is the file named as?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From [Doxygen FAQ](http://www.doxygen.nl/manual/faq.html#faq_code_inc):

> You can also document your class as follows
>
> ```
> /*! \class MyClassName include.h path/include.h
>  *
>  *  Docs for MyClassName
>  */
> ```
>
> To make doxygen put
>
> `#include <path/include.h>`
>
> in the documentation of the class MyClassName regardless of the name
>   of the actual header file in which the definition of MyClassName is
>   contained.

So I would try:

```
/**
* \class MyClass myclass.hpp MyClass
...
*/
```